# this reference inside the construstor

Tags: java, constructor, stack, this

I am watching **Programming Methodology (Stanford) (CS106A)** course on Java . In   [lecture 14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8nNdNZ40EQ&list=EC84A56BC7F4A1F852) Professor *Sahami*  told about memory allocation in Java for functions and object on stack and heap .

He told that for any method called on an object , a stack is allocated and argument list and **this reference** is allocated space on stacke . Through **this refernece** stored, Java is able to refer to the correct instance variables of an object .

[image: stack--when method is called]

but for constructor no **this reference** is stored along with argument list as object is being
constructed. [image: stack -- when constructor is called]

My ques is if constructor don't have have this refernece then how we can use it inside constructor for ex

```
public class foo {
private int i;
public foo(int i)
{this.i = i;// where this reference came from}
                 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is simply a Java keyword that allows you to reference the current object. It can be used in any class.

The purpose of using the `this` keyword is to prevent referencing a local variable.

It is needed in your example, since `i = i` will do absolutely nothing, since both are references to the same local variable (not the class variable):

[From here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.

**EDIT:**

I realize that you may have been asking about the actual memory address.

I imagine

```
class Point
{
  int x, y;
  Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
  void move(int a, int b) { x = a; y = b; }
}
Point p = new Point(3,4);
p.move(1,2);
```

might get translated to something like: (making `this` explicit)

```
class Point
{
  int x, y;
  static Point getPoint(int x, int y)
    { Point this = allocateMemory(Point); this.x = x; this.y = y; }
  static void move(Point this, int a, int b) { this.x = a; this.y = b; }
}
Point p = Point.getPoint(3,4);
Point.move(p, 1, 2);
```

but this would all be on a much lower level, so it wouldn't actually look remotely like this, but it could just be a way for you to think about it.

Comment: @T.J. No, I do not know exactly what happens, just the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

all this does is reference the current object's class level variable.
If the `this` keyword is not used then the variable will be stored in the method level variable.

```
public class foo {
    private int i;

    public foo(int i) {
        this.i = i; // stores the argument i into the class level variable i
    }

    public foo2(int i) {
        i = i;    // stores the argument i into the argument i
    }
}
```